# React Native auto RTL text switch not work in IOS but true in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have problem in iOS Text,
it is my output in android and iOS , but in iOS not true(don't support auto switch rtl in iOS).
And i want to selectable Text.

[image]

this is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
var desc = `English \r\n انگلیسی \r\n Persian \r\n فارسی \r\n Arabic \r\n العربی`;
return (
    <View style={{ padding: 20, paddingTop: 100 }}>
      <TextInput
        selectable={true} 
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        placeholder="Type something"
        placeholderTextColor="grey"
        numberOfLines={10}
        multiline={true}
        value={desc}
      />

      <Text selectable={true}>
        {desc}
      </Text>
    </View>
);
}
```

Comment: Have you find any solutions ?